# How can i fix or handle the Generic error "PAYMENT_ALREADY_DONE" with paypal sandbox?

Tags: paypal, woocommerce

You guys are my last hope... I created a website with WordPress and I'm using woocommerce.  I have been doing test transactions in the PayPal sandbox.   And it was working, but suddenly started to give this error in PayPal

```
/genericError?code=PAYMENT_ALREADY_DONE
```

And each time cancels my orders.   I tried to solve the issue by adding a prefix to the order number but still is giving me that error.  I am only using one shop.

and I've checked everywhere for hours, for most people it was a problem of forgetting to change the sandbox PayPal account to their real business account, for others it was because they weren't using a prefix and had more than one shop. All the others never got any answer or help.

how can i fix this?

By the way, after the process paypal redirects de user to cancel order page of woocomerce  but in the woocomercer order panel  appears te order was made.

in the image below you can see  the order were created and the random prefix and subfix i added to order numbers.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVMNW.png)